# Can't figure out how to Ignore / at the end of an url, in linq comparison

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check if a given url already exists in a table. 
The challenge is that that the urls in the db isn't standardized.

So I want to do something like this:

```
bool UrlAlreadyExists = db.Users.Any(u = u.Url
.TrimEnd('/')
.ToLower()
.Replace("https://, "")
.Replace("http://", "")
.Replace("www", "") 

 == 
newUrl
.TrimEnd('/')
.ToLower()
.Replace("https://, "")
.Replace("http://", "")
.Replace("www", "");
);
```

However I'm not allowed to use `TrimEnd()`, and I'm not sure how to work around that?

Comment: Those replacements show that the problem has nothing to do with `/` at the end. You actually want to match a specific *pattern* that just can't be used with SQL. The pattern itself ingores the `s` in `https` and ignores `www`. Trimming the trailing `/` is trivial, you already have to load everything in memory to find out if there are any matches

Comment: Also, in general case, URL with www. prefix does not have to point to the same IP address as URL without it. The probability that two URLs mean the same is higher than 99%, but it's not 100%.

Comment: Actually coming up with a regex for parsing an URL is a surprisingly complicated matter, given that the URL specification is quite complex. You might be better off using something like `new Uri(uriFromOutside)` and then work with the URI object to produce a normalized version of this.

Comment: If you want good performance you *have* to normalize the URLs in the database and index the field that contains the normalized URLs. The other option is to load all URLs in a list and use a Regex to look for matches. That's far faster than trimming and replacing, which generates *5* extra strings for each input string. Strings are immutable so each string operation creates a new string

Comment: @JanThomä the OP wants to treat http and https the same while ignoring www. The Uri constructor itself isn't enough and probably not a regex either. That process is expensive enough it should be done just once, to generate nomalized URLs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes the urls should be in the DB in some normalized format for efficient querying. I was merely suggesting to use the Uri class for normalizing instead of hacking it with some regex.